# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (5400x64 and 5400x64)

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm working on an image classification network and got a problem with the right values of inputs and outputs in the forward() function. I don't have an idea to solve this, because they seem the same to me. The error comes from this line:
 `x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))`, but I can't figure it out.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

That's my code:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 8, kernel_size=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(8, 12, kernel_size=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(12, 18, kernel_size=2)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(18, 24, kernel_size=2)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(5400, 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 2)

    def forward(self, x):
        print(f'1. {x.size()}')
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(f'2. {x.size()}')
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(f'3. {x.size()}')
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(f'4. {x.size()}')
        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(f'5. {x.size()}')
        x = x.view(-1, x.size(0)) 
        print(f'6. {x.size()}')
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        print(f'7. {x.size()}')
        x = self.fc2(x)
        print(f'8. {x.size()}')
        
        return torch.sigmoid(x)
```

That's the print output:

```
1. torch.Size([64, 3, 256, 256])
2. torch.Size([64, 8, 127, 127])
3. torch.Size([64, 12, 63, 63])
4. torch.Size([64, 18, 31, 31])
5. torch.Size([64, 24, 15, 15])
6. torch.Size([5400, 64])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing

```
x = x.view(-1, x.size(0))
```

to

```
x = x.view([-1, 5400], x.size(0))
```

Will solve your problem, You see that in print 6:

```
6. torch.Size([5400, 64])
```

the batch size `64` is in the `1` axes and not in the `0` axes. The fully connected layer expects an input of size `5400` therefore changing this will likely solve since you do not know that batch size but you know that the input to the fully-connected is `5400`.